# How to add parameters to my url after filling input fields & checking checkbox without submitting the form

Tags: javascript, frontend

I am coding a simple fee calculator, i have some checkbox and text inputs, i need to add the entered values to my url so i can send the url to someone with the same values. i have set the parameters in the value of my fields, for Example :

```
value="<?= isset($_GET['collect']) ? $_GET['collect'] : '0' ?>"
```

Everything works fine when i type the parameters in my url manually, for ex :

**myurl.com/?collect=200&collectBudget=50**

I need to have the parameters dynamically in the url, if check the checkbox or enter a value in the input fields. Hers is an example of the simple calculator https://codepen.io/alchy/pen/xxOQqeO

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite understanding what you want. If someone types in `myurl.com/?collect=200&collectBudget=50` then you want specific fields to be pre-populated? Or, you want the url to change as the user interacts with the input fields?

Comment: i gave an example of static url. Yes i want a changing url whenever the input fields changes ;)

Comment: Do you only want the url to change if the collect or collectBudget fields change? Or any of the input fields (text fields and checkboxes) change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lacking additional information, I've come up with this, it should largely do what you want, but you're going to need decide what you want the url query names to be, how / when you want the url to reset, if you want to show the query values at all when the value is 0 and how you want to parse the checkbox values:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Get the base URL
  const baseUrl = location.href.replace(location.search, '');

  // Find the Input elements
  const collectCheckbox = document.getElementById('collect');
  const platformInput = document.getElementById('nPlatform');
  const platformBudInput = document.getElementById('PlatformBud');
  const displayCheckbox = document.getElementById('display');
  const numStoresInput = document.getElementById('nStores');
  const storeBudInput = document.getElementById('storBud');

  // Attach listeners to the Input elements
  collectCheckbox.addEventListener('change', updateUrl);
  platformInput.addEventListener('input', updateUrl);
  platformBudInput.addEventListener('input', updateUrl);
  displayCheckbox.addEventListener('change', updateUrl);
  numStoresInput.addEventListener('input', updateUrl);
  storeBudInput.addEventListener('input', updateUrl);

  var timeout = null;

  function calculatePrice() {
    var collectCheck = document.getElementById('collect');
    var displayCheck = document.getElementById('display');

    var xPlatfor = document.getElementById('nPlatform').value;
    var pBudget = document.getElementById('PlatformBud').value;

    var xStore = document.getElementById('nStores').value;
    var sBudget = document.getElementById('storBud').value;

    var collectAmount,
      collectBudget,
      displayAmount,
      displayBudget,
      pricePerMonth,
      pricePerYear;
    collectAmount = 0;
    collectBudget = 0;
    displayAmount = 0;
    displayBudget = 0;
    pricePerMonth = 0;
    pricePerYear = 0;

    if (collectCheck.checked == true && xPlatfor > 0 && pBudget > 0) {
      collectAmount = pBudget;
    }
    if (displayCheck.checked == true && xStore > 0 && sBudget > 0) {
      displayAmount = xStore * sBudget;
    }

    pricePerMonth = +collectAmount + +displayAmount;
    pricePerYear = pricePerMonth * 12;

    document.getElementById('pricePerM').innerHTML = pricePerMonth;
    document.getElementById('pricePerY').innerHTML = pricePerYear;
  }

  function updateUrl() {
    if (!(collectCheckbox.checked || displayCheckbox.checked || platformInput.value || platformBudInput.value || numStoresInput.value || storeBudInput.value)) {
      return baseUrl;
    }

    let newUrl = new URL(`${baseUrl}?`);
    collectCheckbox.checked && newUrl.searchParams.append('collect', 1);
    displayCheckbox.checked && newUrl.searchParams.append('display', 1);
    platformInput.value && newUrl.searchParams.append('platforms', platformInput.value);
    platformBudInput.value && newUrl.searchParams.append('platformBudget', platformBudInput.value);
    numStoresInput.value && newUrl.searchParams.append('numStores', numStoresInput.value);
    storeBudInput.value && newUrl.searchParams.append('storeBud', storeBudInput.value);
    history.pushState({}, '', newUrl.toString());
  }

  calculatePrice();

  document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.name == 'question_1') {
      calculatePrice();
    }
  });
});
```

Any questions, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i need, there is only one small issu, the parameters collect or display must not show both if check only one of theme!

Comment: Ok that's cool, I've updated my answer to reflect this. Let me know if everything works fine!

Comment: Glad I could help, all the best!